# Why is this Python regular expression code finding only empty results?

Tags: python, html, regex, parsing, css

The code I have is:

```
    matches = re.search('(<meta.*?>)', contents, re.DOTALL)
    if matches:
        for group in matches.groups():
            metas.append(group)
    title = re.search('(<title>.*?</title>)', contents, re.DOTALL)
    if title.groups():
        found_title = title.group(1) + '\n'
    else:
        found_title = ''
```

It's working on an HTML page that has meta and title tags (lowercase), so I would expect multiple matches for the meta tags and a nonempty title. Adding or removing parentheses around the regular expression does not seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`re.search` searches for the first match. You need to use `re.findall` or `re.finditer`.